ARKit: reproject point to 3D point with depthmap to create a point cloud
With Ipad, I'm trying to create a pointcloud in my ARview using ARFrame.smoothedSceneDepth.depthMap. I know there is a lot of tutorial for this kind of stuff Displaying a Point Cloud Using Scene Depth | Apple Developer Documentation. But I would like to not use shaders and compute in CPU
Here is my main loop for sampling the depthmap and reproject point in 3D
for h in stride(from:Float(0), to:Float(1), by: Float(0.02))
        {
            for w in stride(from:Float(0), to:Float(1), by: Float(0.02))
            {
                let pixelAddressDepth = depthData.getPixAdressValue(h: h, w: w, sizeType: MemoryLayout<Float32>.size)
                let depthValue = pixelAddressDepth.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self).pointee
                let rgb = SIMD3<UInt8>(0,0,0)
                let coord2D = RGBData.getPixIndex(h: h, w: w)
.landscapeRight).inverse)
                let coord3D = worldPoint2(h: h, w: w, eyeDepth: depthValue, cameraIntrinsicsInversed: cameraIntrinsicsInversed, viewMatrixInversed: camera.viewMatrix(for: .landscapeRight).inverse, projectionInversed: viewMatrix.inverse)
                let data = PtData(coord: coord3D, color: rgb)
                self.listPoint.append(data)
            }
        }

The sampling of the depthmap seems correct but the reprojection function worldPoint2 is not and I don't know why :
func worldPoint(cameraPoint: SIMD2<Float>, eyeDepth: Float, cameraIntrinsicsInversed: simd_float3x3, viewMatrixInversed: simd_float4x4) -> SIMD3<Float> {
            let localPoint = cameraIntrinsicsInversed * simd_float3(cameraPoint, eyeDepth)
        let localPoint2 = SIMD4<Float>(localPoint.x,localPoint.y,localPoint.z,1)
            let worldPoint = viewMatrixInversed * localPoint2
            return (worldPoint / worldPoint.w)[SIMD3(0,1,2)];
 
 
     }

    func worldPoint2(h:Float,w:Float, eyeDepth: Float, cameraIntrinsicsInversed: simd_float3x3, viewMatrixInversed: simd_float4x4, projectionInversed: simd_float4x4) -> SIMD3<Float> {
        let NDCPoint = SIMD4(x:w*2.0-1.0, y: h*2.0-1.0,z:eyeDepth,w:1)
            let localPoint = viewMatrixInversed * projectionInversed * NDCPoint
        return (localPoint / localPoint.w)[SIMD3(0,1,2)];

 
 
     }

